# The King's ability to promote a piece

Tags: rules, pawn-promotion, kings

If the King makes it to the eighth rank and then back to the first rank, can he promote a piece like a pawn can when it reaches the eighth rank?

Comment: I should note that any game in which two players agree on the rules is indeed a game. If you have a friend who would be willing to play such a game with you, try it out!! It might be fun! My gut tells me it seems like a terrible waste of 10 something moves and also puts your king in grave danger. Granted, an extra queen is certainly the kind of thing that would make you take such risks, but even that is pretty big.

Comment: @Susan is there some reason that you think that *is* possible? (in which case we can try to clarify your misunderstanding - which rule did you think allowed this?) Or is this intended as just "could you create this random extra rule" (in which case Brian Towers' answer addresses that)

Answer (score 6):

No. The whole point of the game, the way you win, is by checkmating the opponent's king. If your opponent could exchange the king for another piece then you would no longer be able to win.

In any case, all the pieces except the pawns can move backwards. Without promotion any pawn which reached the 8th rank and couldn't promote would no longer be able to move. That doesn't apply to all the other pieces.

FIDE, the international chess federation publishes [the laws of chess](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012018) on their website. The first 5 articles describe the rules for general play. The articles from 6 onwards describe additional rules which apply to official competitions.